# Is there a place where WebDeploy well known parameters are (exhaustively) listed?

Tags: parameters, configuration, msdeploy, webdeploy, convention

It looks like there are some conventions for default parameters one can use with webdeploy, but they are poorly documented (or poorly referenced).

For instance parameters such as `IIS Web Application Name` are well known.

It also looks like connections string parameters have to be in the particular form of `<ConnectionStringName>-Web.config Connection String` when stored in your web.config, where `ConnectionStringName` is the name you used in the web.config ConnectionString name attribute.

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of recognized automatic webDeploy parameters such as IIS site name, AppPool configurations, and so on.

Is this available on MSDN or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any documentation on these default parameters but I think you've covered them all.  I've never seen any other defaults.